# force x and y axes to be drawn at the bottom of wireframe plot (lattice library)

Tags: r, lattice, wireframe

How do I force the *x* and *y* axes of the figure below to be drawn at the bottom of the cube, rather than at the top?

[image]

Currently, the axes are automatically drawn above the cube when the *z* parameter (inside screen=...) falls below -90.

Code used to generate the figure:

```
library(lattice)
D <- expand.grid(x=seq(1,10), y=seq(1,10))
D$z <- D$x-D$y
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data=D, screen=list(z=-120, x=-60))
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?panel.cloud` # since `wireframe` calls `panel.cloud`

> scpos: 
>      A list with three components x, y and z (each a scalar integer), describing which of the 12 sides of the cube the scales should be drawn. The defaults should be OK. Valid values are x: 1, 3, 9, 11; y: 8, 5, 7, 6 and z: 4, 2, 10, 12. (See comments in the source code of panel.cloud to see the details of this enumeration.)

```
# Didn't look up the source code. Was easy enough to experiment
wireframe(z ~ x * y, data=D, screen=list(z=-120, x=-60), scpos=list(x=9,y=5,z=2))
```

[image]